# bfgminer not catching xdotool

Tags: xorg, xdotool, expect

I'm trying to send a short sequence of keystrokes to bfgminer without bringing its window to focus, it is running in a gnome-terminal.

```
#! /bin/bash
xdotool key --window 25165831 p
sleep 1
xdotool key --window 25165831 s
sleep 1
xdotool key --window 25165831 0
```

Nothing happens. Although when I run the following script it works.

```
#! /bin/bash
xdotool windowactivate 25165831
sleep 1
xdotool key p
sleep 1
xdotool key s
sleep 1
xdotool key 0
```

I have looked into `expect` but it is large and complex, i'm just looking for a short an simple solution. Although it seems from what I read that `expect` could get the job done. Maybe using expect would be better if xdotool conflicts with user interaction while it is executing my script.
Any help is appreciate! :)

Answer (score 0):

Many programs do not accept key strokes when they do not have the keyboard forcus - which certainly makes some sense.

But you do not need to use "windowactivate", "windowfocus" works, and does not bring the window to front etc.:
`xdotool windowfocus 8392809 key p`

Also, you can simplify your command to one line by using the `sleep` command of `xdotool`

`xdotool key p sleep 0.5 key s`

or by using the option `--delay` with the command `key`.

---

As background: The commands you tried look very similar, but have a technical difference, explained in `man xdotool`:

```
SENDEVENT NOTES
    If you are trying to send key input to a specific window, and it does not appear to be working, then it's
    likely your application is ignoring the events xdotool is generating. This is fairly common.

    Sending keystrokes to a specific window uses a different API than simply typing to the active window. If you
    specify 'xdotool type --window 12345 hello' xdotool will generate key events and send them directly to window
    12345.  However, X11 servers will set a special flag on all events generated in this way (see
    XEvent.xany.send_event in X11's manual). Many programs observe this flag and reject these events.

    It is important to note that for key and mouse events, we only use XSendEvent when a specific window is
    targeted. Otherwise, we use XTEST.

    Some programs can be configured to accept events even if they are generated by xdotool. Seek the documentation
    of your application for help.

    Specific application notes (from the author's testing): * Firefox 3 seems to ignore all input when it does not
    have focus.  * xterm can be configured while running with ctrl+leftclick, 'Allow SendEvents' * gnome-terminal
    appears to accept generated input by default.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. near the end of this project i started to consider pluging into the bfgminer api